# jQuery ajaxSetup beforeSend not executing in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

My project uses jQuery 1.4.2.
I've got some security information that I add to my AJAX headers... 
The way I'm doing this is by using $.ajaxSetup(), and setting a beforeSend function.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        global: true,
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            var verificationToken = 'some encrypted string';
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Request-Verification-Token", verificationToken);
        }
    });
})
```

As I understand it, this should then execute every time I make a call to $.ajax(), right?
It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, and so on, but occasionally *not* in IE7/8.

Here's where I call it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: 'somedata',
    url: "/some/url",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

I've found a workaround, which is to add the beforeSend directly to the $.ajax() call (below), but I really want to do this globally, rather than have to add it to loads of places in the code...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: 'somedata',
    url: "/some/url",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("error");
    }
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        var verificationToken = 'some encrypted string';
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Request-Verification-Token", verificationToken);
    }
});
```

Any clues?

Thanks!
Neil

Comment: possible to update jquery version ? the problem here is 1.4version of Jquery using XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Tricky to update jQuery... It's used pretty heavily in the site, and could be a pain to retest everything. Are there any major API changes between 1.4.x and 1.5?

Comment: Not sure, gonna read through bro.

Comment: I KNOW this is old, but is your ajax call and ajaxSetup call in the same document ready wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in the absence of any other answer, I hereby declare this to be a bug in JQuery 1.4.x.
The solution is to upgrade to a later version of JQuery, which sadly isn't possible for me.

If anyone has any better answer/fix, I'll happily delete this one, and mark theirs as correct.

Comment: Its not a jQuery upgrade. I see the same thing in jQuery 1.8

Comment: I'm getting this in 1.10.3

Comment: I couldn't find jquery v1.10.3 anywhere. But for the v1.10.2 it fixed. but strange that for the v1.12.4, it didn't work for me