# beforeSend not working in internet explorer while using ajax in jquery

Tags: jquery

I was tring to add a loading gif image on the div before the content was generated. it works fine in firefox but does not function in internet explorer. below are my code

thanks heaps

```
<script type="text/javascript">
j(document).ready(function() {

    j('#sliderform').submit(function() {
    //j('#dash1').html('loading....');

    bodyContent = j.ajax({

        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#dash1").append('abhinab...');
            //alert("loading,..");
            j('#dash').html('loading....');
            j('#dash').html('<img src="../resources/images/loading.gif" >');
    //document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = '<img src="../resources/images/loading.gif" >';
        //  document.getElementById('dash').innerHTML = '<img src="../resources/images/loading.gif" >';         
           },

          url: "dashboardreload.php",
          global: true,
          type: "POST",
          data: ({min : j("#min").val(),max : j("#max").val()}),
          dataType: "html",
          async:false,
          success: function(msg){
             // drawChart();

          }
       }
    ).responseText;
    //j('#dialog-form').html('');
    //j( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
    //document.getElementById('dash').innerHTML = '<img src="../resources/images/loading.gif" >';
    j('#dash').html(bodyContent);

    drawChart();

    //confirm(bodyContent);
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.4 then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817238/jquery-ajaxsetup-beforesend-not-executing-in-ie8 might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "var" before every variable:

```
var bodyContent = j.ajax({....
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's see. @ArtoAle's reply is well taken: don't use global variables.

The real thing to note is that you are making a synchronous call to ajax (the `async` property is `false`). That will block the UI thread JavaScript is running on until it resumes once the data has been returned. Maybe in IE, the changes to the DOM aren't rendered while the UI thread is blocked, but they do in Firefox? Dunno, but I would certainly make the call an asynchronous one.

If that is done, `beforeSend` works for me here in the manner you describe with IE8 and jQuery 1.6.1.